# Why does Illustrator CS6 "Save for Microsoft Office" use PNG format?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, microsoft-office

I recently made some graphs in Illustrator CS6 to insert into a MS Word document. I created my original images using the Print profile with PPI set to 300. I used the "Save for Microsoft Office" option to export the images for Word. Why does this option create a PNG file (with a resolution of 150) as opposed to using, say, TIFF or EPSF format? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's the best, most reliable, format for Office.

If you're saving something for Office, chances are it is ***not*** going to be commercially printed. In that case, 150ppi is plenty for most home/office inkjet printers. In addition, only an RGB image is needed. Of the standard RGB formats, PNG24 supports transparency the best. So, 150ppi, RGB, transparent image = PNG24.

There's no call for a tiff or eps if using Office. The advantages of a TIF/EPS using CMYK color are pointless since Office doesn't use CMYK color. The advantages of an EPS being resolution independent are largely lost on the average Office user.

Comment: +1, also, MS Office *ruins* pretty much every vector format going. It's often capable of embedding many types of vector files, but in my experience makes an absolute hash of everything, even the Microsoft-invented formats like WMF. PNGs, however, are difficult to ruin...

Answer (score 3):

The best way to use graphics for MS office tools is `.WMF` or `.EMF` formats.
These formats truly supports and gives the freedom to re-edit it in MS office itself.

Try to use this by exporting from any Vector tools like Coreldraw or Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: I didn't make good experiences with neither .emf nor .wmf when exporting from Adobe Illustrator. For satisfactory results, one might have to restrict the features used in illustrator, but then I was not eager enough to figure out which ones work.